# How to make React responsive? Struggling to think in the React way

Tags: css, reactjs, responsive-design

I'm still a bit new to ReactJS, and so I've been kind of struggling with implementing React components in a responsive manner.

I'm using [react-tabs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-tabs) in my app. This is fine when the width is wide enough, but once I shrink it down to a phone size, I would like to make a hamburger panel.

So, how would I go about this? Do I check for the width constantly in the component, where I make a conditional if-else block rendering either the Tabs component or the Hamburger panel component?

There has to be an easy way to go about this. But I'm a bit lost on how to do it.

Comment: This is entirely a function of CSS and has nothing to do with React. You should choose a responsive framework for your CSS that has the functionality you need.

Comment: But I would still need to have a different component for the hamburger panel, right? Or I would just completely change the look of the react-tabs through css only?

Comment: I certainly think that this should be solved in React. I actually solved a smiler issue in work project. Drawing up an example now.

Comment: Look at this responsive CSS example https://github.com/petermoresi/react-responsive-menu . It doesn't look like a hamburger, but you get the point.

Comment: @Fo. Thank you for that example. So basically, I could have an element which represents the the hamburger icon. Hide the element initially, and only display it with if the width is small enough using media queries. In the same media query, change how the tabs look as well so that they fit in the panel properly.
Does this sound correct?

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of how I have dealt with this issue in the past.

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            screenIsbig: true
        };
    }

    handleResize() {
        if(window.innerWidth < 1200) {
            this.setState({screenIsbig: false})
        } else {
            this.setState({screenIsbig: true});
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResize.bind(this));
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', this.handleResize.bind(this));
    }

    render() {
        let renderThis;
        if(this.state.screenIsbig) {
            renderThis = <h1>This is for big screens</h1>
        } else {
            renderThis = <h3>This is for small screens</h3>
        }
        return (
            <div>
                {renderThis}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```